# Sub-assign rows by reference using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data.table:

```
DT1 <- data.table(col1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), col2 = letters[1:7], col3 = rep(TRUE,7))

   col1 col2 col3
1:    1    a TRUE
2:    2    b TRUE
3:    3    c TRUE
4:    4    d TRUE
5:    5    e TRUE
6:    6    f TRUE
7:    7    g TRUE
```

Then I define:

```
vec <- c(2,5,6)
```

And with:

```
DT1[col1 == vec, col3 := FALSE]
```

I obtain:

```
   col1 col2  col3
1:    1    a  TRUE
2:    2    b  TRUE
3:    3    c  TRUE
4:    4    d  TRUE
5:    5    e FALSE
6:    6    f FALSE
7:    7    g  TRUE
```

I expect `col3` of second line to be set to `FALSE` here, which seems to be not the case.

But for example, this works as I expect:

```
DT1[vec, col3 := FALSE]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `DT1[col1%in%vec, col3:=FALSE]`.  If you just use `DT1[col1==vec]` will get the warning that longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.table` has the format `DT[i,j,by]` with `i` meaning `location / where`, `j` meaning `select / update / compute / assign` and `by` meaning `group by`.

So the mistake that you are making here is the following:

In your assignment: `DT1[col1==vec, ...]` part is equivalent to the following index:

```
DT1$col1 == vec
```

This is like comparing the elements `col1` column of `DT1` with `vec`. Since `vec` has only 3 elements, the elements are rolled over, and due to specific values in your `vec` and `col1`, the 5th and 6th elements turns out to be TRUE after rolling.

The correct way to do what you want to do is:

Method 1: (preferred)

```
DT1[vec, col3 := FALSE]
```

Method 2: (equivalent to data.frame, but not preferred for data.table)

```
DT1$col3[vec] <- FALSE
```

or, the following will also work:

```
DT1[vec]$col3 <- FALSE
```

Method 3: Here is another possibility (although slower than the first method):

```
DT1[col1 %in% vec, col3 := FALSE]
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

Use `%in%` as it returns a logical vector:

```
> DT1<-data.table(col1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),col2=letters[1:7],col3=rep(TRUE,7))
> vec <- c(2,5,6)
> DT1[col1 %in% vec, col3 := FALSE]
> DT1
   col1 col2  col3
1:    1    a  TRUE
2:    2    b FALSE
3:    3    c  TRUE
4:    4    d  TRUE
5:    5    e FALSE
6:    6    f FALSE
7:    7    g  TRUE
```